# Can you glue rigid foam board to sill plate?

Tags: walls, insulation, basement, foundation

I was looking for rigid foam to cover my entire 9 ft basement foundation wall and noticed that only 8 foot rigid foam boards were in stock locally. It is 9 feet from the bottom of my ceiling joist to the floor, about 6 inches of that height is the silled plates and the rest concrete. Currently I have fiberglass insulation hung in the ceiling.

If I cut up an additional foam board can I use the same glue on the wood sill plates as I used on the concrete?

Comment: Most of the heat lost in basement walls is at the top above ground and about three or four feet below.  The bottom section usually needs little insulation, if any.  Bigger bang for your money at the top half than bottom.

Comment: @crip659, I can still meet code if the bottom is left exposed?

Comment: Will need to check with your local building department to what is local code.  It is unfortunate that code might not allow the best use of your money, but I would use the cheapest safe insulation at the bottom if needed.

Comment: I don't see the big deal? - one 8 foot sheet yields 8 1-foot filler pieces. Or cut three in 4 foot, six in 5 and 3 foot, get eight 9's (six 4+5 and two 3+3+3)

Comment: @isherwood, I clarified and changed question regarding glue compatibility - which I probably can just look at a label now, but at least the question is out there.

Comment: Fair enough, but we can't possibly answer without knowing _what_ glue we're discussing. You're right--the label should tell you.